# Not able to read input till newline

Tags: c++

```
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        j=0;
        while(j < 100 && (scanf("%d%1[^\n]s", &b[j]) == 1)){
            a[b[j]]++;
            j++;
        }
        cout<<j<<endl;
    }
```

Not able to input values till new line.
I want to count the number of values in a particular line and then input the value of j,
Please help.

Comment: Or 1% invalid C... ;)

Comment: There's already a function that reads input until a newline: `std::getline`

Comment: @crashmstr Not necessarily. So long as the scanf is correct, what does it matter a cout is used later on?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string line;
    int n = 3;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        getline(cin, line);
        cout << line.size() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int len, n = 3;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        scanf("%*[^\n]%n%*c", &len);
        printf("%d\n", len);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to access the values in the line as well.

Comment: @user3717384 use `getline(cin, line);`

Comment: or if `char b[100]` then `scanf("%99[^\n]%n%*c", b, &len);`